# bootstrap php pass parameters to popup modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having problems with a popup modal box.

For some reason, the dialog box isn't displaying the text passed inside the `<a>` tag where `data-soldusers=\"$soldUsersstr\"`. I am using `base64_encode` to encode the string which contains `<select><option>` html tag. And then passes it to a popup dialog using the bootstrap framework.

***php file:***

```
$soldUsersstr=base64_encode($soldUsersstr);

echo "<p><div class=\"user-ads-action\"><a class=\"btn btn-info btn-xs\"  data-toggle=\"modal\"   href=\"#markSoldAds\"   data-soldusers=\"$soldUsersstr\"  $str> <i class=\"fa fa-mail-forward\"></i>".$this->lang->line('MarkSold')." </a></div></p>";
```

***modal php:***

```
<div   id="divSoldUser" name="divSoldUser"  class="center">

</div>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#markSoldAds').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
        $("#postID").val($(event.relatedTarget).data('id'));
         $("#divSoldUser").html(jsbase64_decode($(event.relatedTarget).data('soldusers')));
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your modal is opening ?

Comment: @NanaPartykar What do you mean?

Comment: I'm asking whether his modal is opening or not ? @RyanFung

Comment: @NanaPartykar I don't think his modal was opened yet when those variables are set in the a tag